# ThreeJs - Building a Timeline component in ThreeJS

Tags: timeline, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to build a Timeline component in ThreeJS, similar to this one:
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/groups/groupsEditable.html

What will be the first steps and do I need ThreeJS or other WebGL libraries for it?

Answer (score 0):

check out this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_periodictable

I think it comes pretty close to your example:

[image]